# Enable symlink for nginx config files

Tags: nginx, centos, symbolic-link

I have NGINX running on CentOS7. And I would like to share the `/etc/nginx` directory between Linux and Windows.

The reason is that, I don't want to access the file every time I need to change/add hosts or play around with different configurations. For this I mounted the `/etc/nginx` dir to a folder on my Windows desktop as:

```
sudo mount -t vboxsf nginx /etc/nginx
```

Everything worked, and I can access both file and make an edit, but for some reason NGINX won't restart and this error is all I get.

```
[root@localhost]# systemctl status nginx.service
â nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-01-06 07:02:54 EST; 17s ago
     Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
  Process: 3096 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 06 07:02:54 aphrodite systemd[1]: Starting nginx - high performance web server...
Jan 06 07:02:54 aphrodite nginx[3096]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (13: Permission denied)
Jan 06 07:02:54 aphrodite nginx[3096]: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
Jan 06 07:02:54 aphrodite systemd[1]: nginx.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jan 06 07:02:54 aphrodite systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.
Jan 06 07:02:54 aphrodite systemd[1]: Unit nginx.service entered failed state.
Jan 06 07:02:54 aphrodite systemd[1]: nginx.service failed.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

nginx can't read it's main configuration file, as seen in the service status output you have provided:

```
Jan 06 07:02:54 aphrodite nginx[3096]: nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf" failed (13: Permission denied
```

Fix the ownership/mod of the file (with chown, chmod) and use a different approach to access nginx folder from Windows, as most like that has mixed up the file permissions.

Comment: also check the selinux contexts of the files.

Comment: Ah! It worked with `chmod 777 /etc/nginx -R` but not with `chown` root or nginx. i know chmod 777 bad, but it's only for development

Comment: The issue is that vboxfs doesn't do permissions properly and nginx drops to www-data or www or httpd or something like that from root after it's started and then no longer has access to those files.

Comment: please do not leave `/etc/nginx` with full write privileges...this will lead to a whole load of problems later.